# Printing postorder tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree

while printing the postorder of the tree, i kept getting None as the last value
I have no idea which part i did wrong[image]

```
def postorder(tree):
if tree != None :
    postorder(tree.get_left_subtree())
    postorder(tree.get_right_subtree())
    print(tree.get_value(),end = "")
```

Comment: What do you think could've gone wrong?

Comment: i should use return rather than printing it, but i don't know how to return it

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def postorder(tree):
    if tree.is_empty():
        return ""
    return (
        postorder(tree.get_left_subtree())
        + postorder(tree.get_right_subtree())
        + str(tree.root.value)
    )
```

note that since I don't know the api for your tree so I made up some functions/fields for the tree. `tree.is_empty()` return `True` if the tree has no elements, `tree.root.value` is the value of the root of the current tree.